# How can I compile an existing project of Haskell that has threepenny-gui library on windows?

Tags: user-interface, haskell, threepenny-gui

threepenny-gui: GUI framework that uses the web browser as a display.

Comment: Um… I’d quite like to answer this, seeing as I have some experience with `threepenny-gui`, but what exactly is your question here? Have you tried just using a normal `stack build` or `cabal build`? (If not, that’s what you should try first.) If you have, did you run into any problems? If so, which problem(s) did you encounter, and what actions (if any) have you tried in order to fix it?

Comment: (Oh, and I think it’s worth noting that I’ve been having some [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64021952/unable-to-load-package-regex-posix-unknown-symbol-regerror) with compiling `threepenny-gui` recently… hopefully someone will find a solution soon, but until then you may end up running into that problem when you try building it.)

Comment: Well I added threepenny-gui as dependency like this `extra-deps: - threepenny-gui-0.9.0.0` to stack.yaml file but it says the project doesn't contains local packages when I do stack buid.

Comment: You shouldn’t need to use `extra-deps` with `threepenny-gui`, since `threepenny-gui` is already in Stackage. What error message are you getting?